# How can I concatenate an output from xargs in a variable?

Tags: string, shell, output, gentoo

On the code bellow I need to provide a complete output on the variable "depend" before moving to the next loop. Also, testing the command "equery" manually I have seen that after a number of arguments the next ones are dumped directly on the terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

depend=$(equery depends "$@" | awk '{gsub("./*"," ",$1); gsub("-[0-9].*," ",$1); print $1}')

until
    new=""
    depend=$(echo $depend | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs)
    echo $depend
    new=$(equery depends `echo $depend` | xargs -n50 | awk '{gsub("./*"," ",$1); gsub("-[0-9].*," ",$1); print $1}')
    depend=$new
    [ -z $depend ]
do :; done
```

Comment: "\`echo $depend\`" - just `"$depend"`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the reverse dependencies of packages, both direct and indirect, which makes you use recursion.
The `equery` command provides an option to look for indirect dependencies : `-D` or `--indirect`. There is another option that should be used simultaneously `--depth=NUM` because many packages are in dependencies loops ! (I just discovered it while working on your script) It makes me think that the package manager must be really smart to escape those loops !

For example the reverse dependencies tree of VLC looks like :

```
$ equery --quiet depends --indirect vlc
media-libs/phonon-vlc-0.11.1
 media-libs/phonon-4.11.1-r1
  kde-apps/kio-extras-19.12.2
   kde-plasma/plasma-workspace-5.17.5-r1
    virtual/notification-daemon-0
     x11-libs/libnotify-0.7.8
      media-video/vlc-3.0.8
(Many other reverse dependencies removed)
```

It's not a good idea to remove the category from a package name, because there are packages with the same name in different categories, even when excluding special categories (`virtual`, `acct-user`, `acct-group`) :

```
app-vim/json
dev-haskell/json
dev-java/json
dev-ruby/json
```

You can find them with the command :

```
cd /var/db/repos/gentoo/;ls -1d */*|grep -v "^acct-"|grep -v virtual|cut -d '/' -f2|sort|uniq -c|sort -n|tail -n50
```

Getting back to your script, I've made modifications to make it work. The most important thing is putting `"` around `equery` calls or variable names to keep line separators when necessary. I believe this script will not terminate if a package is in a dependencies loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

depend="$(echo "$@" | xargs -n1 equery depends | awk '{gsub("-[0-9].*","",$1); print $1}')"

until
    depend="$(echo "$depend" | sort -u)"
    test="$depend"
    echo Reverse dependencies
    echo "$depend"
    new="$(echo $depend | xargs -n1 equery depends | awk '{gsub("-[0-9].*","",$1); print $1}')"
    depend="$new"
    [ -z "$test" ]
do :; done
```